# Jmeter - Convert JSON names to an Array using Groovy/JSR223

Tags: java, json, groovy, jmeter

I need help converting JSON names to array.

```
{
    "success":true,
    "message":"Unable to get a list of active campaigns",
    "data":{
        "campaign_list":{
            "80f6af8a-9565-11e8-b82b-02f91108fe5a":{},
            "99d5d15c-9565-11e8-aa56-02f91108fe5a":{}
        },
        "target_list":{
            "44d84c8a-8574-11e8-bbe9-02f91108fe5a":{},
            "4fa407a2-8575-11e8-9886-02f91108fe5a":{},
            "ee35e2ba-8579-11e8-b1a3-02f91108fe5a":{},
            "6ced8b0c-857b-11e8-868c-02f91108fe5a":{}
        }
    }
}
```

I need the names under `campaign_list` and `target_list` to be stored in an array like this:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "message":"Unable to get a list of active campaigns",
    "data":{
        "campaign_list":[
            "80f6af8a-9565-11e8-b82b-02f91108fe5a":{},
            "99d5d15c-9565-11e8-aa56-02f91108fe5a":{}
        ],
        "target_list":[
            "44d84c8a-8574-11e8-bbe9-02f91108fe5a":{},
            "4fa407a2-8575-11e8-9886-02f91108fe5a":{},
            "ee35e2ba-8579-11e8-b1a3-02f91108fe5a":{},
            "6ced8b0c-857b-11e8-868c-02f91108fe5a":{}
        ]
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as your second example is not a valid JSON, you can check it yourself using an [online JSON Validator](https://jsonlint.com/).

Normally you should be able to use [JSONSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) and [JSONBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) combination like:

```
log.info('Original: ' + prev.getResponseDataAsString())
def original = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(original)
static def map2list(Map m) {
    def l = []
    m.each() { k, v -> l << k }
    return l;
}
builder.content.data.campaign_list = map2list(original.data.campaign_list)
builder.content.data.target_list = map2list(original.data.target_list)
log.info('Converted: ' + builder.toPrettyString())
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Convert Map to List]

The above code produces valid JSON and converts a list of JSON Objects into a JSON Array. Check out the following material if you need more information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

---

If you need to convert the JSON into some weird structure you posted - I'm afraid you will have to treat it as plain text therefore use [Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to change `{` to `[` where required.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I just realized that the one I want is an invalid JSON. And sorry for not clarifying what data to be extracted. What I really need is the list of Key/s under `target_list`, so is it possible to get the key/s and store in array? Note that both `target_list` and `campaign_list` are both dynamic. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Below is some code to get you started. I used the library: `groovy.json.JsonSlurper`
You can use (https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-groovy-online) to try and run the code below.
Hope it helps!

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

def object = jsonSlurper.parseText('{"success":true,"message":"Unable to get a list of active campaigns","data":{"campaign_list":{"80f6af8a-9565-11e8-b82b-02f91108fe5a":{},"99d5d15c-9565-11e8-aa56-02f91108fe5a":{}},"target_list":{"44d84c8a-8574-11e8-bbe9-02f91108fe5a":{},"4fa407a2-8575-11e8-9886-02f91108fe5a":{},"ee35e2ba-8579-11e8-b1a3-02f91108fe5a":{},"6ced8b0c-857b-11e8-868c-02f91108fe5a":{}}}}')

println(object.success);
println(object.data.campaign_list);
```

Once you have retrieved the object, you can use the following below to get your array:

```
def arr = object.data.campaign_list as String[]
println arr[0]
println arr[1]
```